# How to verify BAZEL project for correctness?

Tags: bazel

How can I verify that my entire project does not contain errors (say, references to targets which are not declared anywhere)?
In a static language, whenever my code references something that doesn't exist, I get compiler errors. Is there a way to perform an equivalent check with bazel?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`bazel build --nobuild //...` has a similar effect. It evaluates all the rules (and fails with any errors), but doesn't actually build anything.

Add any additional flags you would with a full build you're checking against. Most flags result in rules evaluating differently, so you might see different errors depending on what flags you use.

A set of Bazel targets can build correctly for some [configurations](https://docs.bazel.build/versions/main/skylark/rules.html#configurations) but not others. For example, if there's a [select](https://docs.bazel.build/versions/main/be/functions.html#select) without a default like this:

```py
cc_library(
    name = "something",
    srcs = select({
        ":cpu_k8": ["something_k8.cc"],
    }),
)
```

then it will build with `--cpu=k8` but not `--cpu=aarch64`. This means you have to specify the same set of flags when checking as with a full build.